# Google Maps: Javascript equivalent of Python's "All" to check to see if a marker is a member of multiple categories?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm putting down markers via the Google Maps API based on checkboxes.  I want the map to show only markers that are the intersection of all checked checkboxes.

I have function `getCheckedBoxes(chkboxName)` which will return an array containing the IDs of all checkedBoxes.

Function `show` displays markers based on whether they have that ID inside of one of their category properties.

```
function show(category, type) {
   var checkedBoxes = getCheckedBoxes("checkbox");
   if (checkedBoxes !== null) {
       for (var i=0; i<checkedBoxes.length; i++) {
            for (var n=0; n<gmarkers.length; n++) {
                if (gmarkers[n][category].toUpperCase().indexOf(checkedBoxes[i].toUpperCase()) !== -1) {
                    gmarkers[n].setVisible(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        }


   // == check the checkbox ==
   document.getElementById(type+" box").checked = true;
```

}

the problem line is obviously `if (gmarkers[i][category].toUpperCase().indexOf(checkedBoxes[i].toUpperCase()) !== -1)` which will cause the markers to be plot if it is satisfied only once.  I need something like Python's all to ensure that 'TRUE' has to appear for every iteration.

Any ideas?

Dr. Molle suggested using `every`, but I can't seem to think of how it would work.  Something like this?

```
function insideChecked(marker, category) {
        var checkedBoxes = getCheckedBoxes("checkbox");
        for (var i=0; i<checkedBoxes.length; i++) {
            if (marker[category].toUpperCase().indexOf(checkedBoxes[i].toUpperCase()) == -1) {
                return false;
            }
    return true
```

`gmarker.every(insideChecked);`  ?

I solved it with this, but I would still like to know a better way to solve this issue:

```
function show(category, type) {
        var tracker = 0;
        var checkedBoxes = getCheckedBoxes("checkbox");
        for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
            if (checkedBoxes !== null) {
                for (var n=0; n<checkedBoxes.length; n++) {
                    if (gmarkers[i][category].toUpperCase().indexOf(checkedBoxes[n].toUpperCase()) !== -1) {
                        //found a match
                        tracker+=1;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (tracker == checkedBoxes.length) {
                gmarkers[i].setVisible(true);
                tracker = 0;
            }

            else {
                gmarkers[i].setVisible(false);
                tracker = 0; 
            }

        }       
    }
```

Comment: how many categories do you have?

Comment: right now there are 18, but it is likely going to change.  But it shouldn't matter, right?  As you can just call `checkedBoxes.length` and make sure that the number of iterations is equal to that

Comment: When you could be sure that the number of categories does not exceed 32, I would suggest another approach, the use of bitwise operators. You would be able to store  up to 32 categories in 1 Number. Instead of iterating over the checkboxes **and** markers you only need  to sum the values of the checked boxes and use the result for a  bitwise operation on each marker-category.

Comment: The categories would probably exceed 32 at some point.

Comment: Too bad, then take a look at [**Array.every**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fevery)

Comment: This looks like what I need, but I'm having a hard time conceptualizing how to apply it here.  Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure about the structure of `gmarkers[n][category]` and for which purposes you need the `category`-argument for the function.

Comment: category can contain either skills, interests, or languages.  A specific gmarker[n] with a specified category will return a string of  comma delimited skills, interests or languages (depending on the category).

Comment: It would be simple to write something that would work except for `markers[i][category]` which, without seeing how `markers` is constructed, makes little sense. `markers[i].categories` would make more sense.

Comment: You're right. I ended up doing that